# Python, change value of the arguments within the function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to change the value of the list that i put as argument in the function.

this is the code:

```
def shuffle(xs,n=1):
if xs: #if list isn't empty
    if n>0:
        #gets the index of the middle of the list 
        sizel=len(xs)
        midindex=int((sizel-1)/2) 
        for times in range(n):
            xs=interleave(xs[0:midindex],xs[midindex:sizel])
return None
```

The interleave code returns a list with the values of both lists mixed up.

However when i run:

```
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
shuffle(t,n=2)
print t
```

The list t didn't changed it's order. The function needs to return None so i can jst use t=shuffle(t,n). There's anyway i can do this?

Comment: *"The function needs to return None so i can jst use t=shuffle(t,n)."* - that doesn't make any sense. Why don't you `return xs` at the end of your `shuffle` function, and then do `t = shuffle(t, n)`?

Comment: Why must it return `None`? (which incidently, it does by default when you omit the return statement)

Comment: I explained in the comment of the first answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`xs` is a reference local to the function, and is independant of `t`. When you reassign `xs`, `t` still points to the original list.

Since you must not return anything from the function, a workaround is to keep a reference to the original list and repopulate it using slice assignment:

```
orig_xs = xs
# do stuff here
orig_xs[:] = xs
```

Comment: So there's no way i can change t within the function?

Comment: In the assigments specifically says that the function should return None. When i searched this nline i saw that lists are mutable so i should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is right here:

```
xs=interleave(xs[0:midindex],xs[midindex:sizel])
```

You're making slices of the list to pass to your `interleave()` function. These are essentially copies of part of the list. There's no way that what comes back from the function can be anything than a different list from `xs`.

Fortunately, you can just reassign the new list you get back into the original list. That is, keep `xs` pointing to the same list, but replace *all the items in it* with what you get back from the `interleave()` function.

```
xs[:]=interleave(xs[0:midindex],xs[midindex:sizel])
```

This is called a slice assignment. Since `xs` remains the same list that was passed in, all references to the list outside the function will also see the changes.